# Symfony 2: EntityManager cascade persist when not requested

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've an object (Hotel) with relationship "OneToMany" to another object (City).

When saving the object "Hotel" the persistCadade triggers an persist on object "City", which then tries to make an insert.

I might understand the fact that it wants to insert if persist is requested. I in fact have to make some changes in the City objects, but I don't need those changes to be saved.

My Hotel object should only be updated with the correct city_id and not matter about what's happening on the city object as I haven't mentioned any "cascade persist".

Any idea on what might be causing the issue?

Hotel Class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="XYZ\Entity\City")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $city;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Entities which are already persistent are updated regardless of a call to `persist()` in Doctrine 2. See: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#synchronization-with-the-database

Comment: Do you see a way not to PERSIST this object?

Answer (score 2):

The `City` Object you're passing to the `Hotel` object has to be persisted in order to have a primary key (which will be used as foreign key).

It's not possible to get the `city_id` without having a persisted `City` object.

Comment: Definitly, but this City object is already persisted. Basicaly in my Hotel form, I've a drop down with available cities (already persisted) and when selecting one of them I just want the ID to be saved in my hotel nothing on the City should occur.

Comment: It's maybe coming from the persistance sate of your `City` entity. It's possible it's not in state "PERSISTED" for Doctrine's UnitOfWork. Try to do `$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($city);`. It occurs when you instanciate your `City` class without passing by doctrine.

Comment: State returned is "STATE_MANAGED"

Comment: ha! Strange, then. It still tries to insert this city object ? Are you sure you have not created a second `City` instance somewhere else ? You can always verify this using `spl_object_hash($entity)` and compare results to check that the insertion is not caused by another (not managed) entity.

Comment: Mhhh my mistake... Actually City contains a relationship to cityTranslation and this is the object it tries to insert.
In any case the objective here is not to trigger any persist on any relationship if not requested..

Comment: From the docs: `The synchronization involves writing any updates to persistent entities and their relationships to the database.` - As far as I understood you you changed something inside the relationship. This WILL be persisted if you `flush()` your UnitOfWork. Maybe detatching the City entity from the UnitOfWork/EntityManager does the trick.

Comment: I tried the following code:
foreach($entity->getCity()->getTranslations() as $e) echo $e->getId();

$entity being the Hotel entity. 
I get an ID for each translation, which is normal as they are already exsiting, so how come it wants to INSERT a new translation as already having id for each of them? Not too sure on what to test ...